# Validating nginx conf file

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use nginx to validate its conf file but I am seeing some strange errors:

```
$ nginx -t  -c `pwd`/foo.conf ; echo $?
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: the configuration file /home/ubuntu/foo.conf syntax is ok
2015/03/24 01:13:08 [emerg] 8464#0: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /home/ubuntu/foo.conf test failed
1
```

whereas this works, though it still prints the error message:

```
$ nginx -t  -c `pwd`/foo.conf -s stop ; echo $?
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: the configuration file /home/ubuntu/foo.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /home/ubuntu/foo.conf test is successful
0
```

Passing `-g 'error_log /tmp/error.log;'` seems to have no effect.

This is the conf file:

```
events  {}
http{
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /ui {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/ui;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: As I recall, nginx -- at least the default install using the tarball and running make install -- doesn't create the log directory (/var/log/nginx). You should create it manually or have your startup script check for the log directory and create it. As for checking the conf, just use -t to validate the configuration file. Your adding an additional -s command to send a signal is telling nginx to do 2 different things in one command.

Comment: As shown above, If I remove the signal, the `nginx` command no longer works. As far as the log, I tried using `-g` to change the directory but that did not work. I would like to run the `nginx` command without `sudo`.

Comment: I think the default nginx command requires root privileges to run -- i.e. if your configuration is using ports below 1024 (that includes ports 80, 443, etc.). Most of the directories nginx writes to also belong to root. So unless you configure your nginx.conf to use non-privileged ports and use user-writable directories you will likely get errors.

Comment: FWIW, adding `-s stop` allows the validation command to run correctly without `sudo`. It just prints the warning. Running without that flag causes the command to fail. Also nginx should not be running after validation is complete. The program is supposed to exit.

Comment: You can try to use the "user" directive to run nginx under a certain user/group. See; http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user

Comment: When nginx runs it writes to /var/run/pid -- I think regardless of whether it's validating the config or not. If you're running nginx as a non-privileged user, you will get the permission denied error (having to do with its inability to write to /var/run). The same goes for the permission error writing to the log file (/var/log/nginx/error.log).